# Selecting checked values from check boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

I'm getting values to my html table using java script. Then i want to passed checked check box values back to my server. But following script function always gives an empty selected array.

```
function find() {

    var dataObject = {};
    var selected = [];
    var i;

    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {
        selected.push($(this).val());
    });

    for (var i = 0, len = selected.length; i < len; i++) {
        dataObject['id' + (i+1)] = (selected[i]);

    }
```

Here is the received html values

```
<td>
     <input type="checkbox" tr.id="0" value="0">
</td>
```

Comment: where you call the find() function?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(":checkbox").change(function() {
  var dataObject = {};
  var selected = [];
  var i;
  $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).val());
  });

  //for (var i = 0, len = selected.length; i < len; i++) {
  //  dataObject['id' + (i + 1)] = (selected[i]);

  //}
  console.log(selected)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" tr.id="0" value="0">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You are not calling the function. Add event handler on checkbox then push the data in the array

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function findcheck() {

            var selected = [];

            $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);

                if ( $this.is(':checked') == true) {
                    selected.push( $this.val() );           
                }

            });

        }

findcheck();
```

[fiddlelink](https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/4jqhjsju/)